# Underfitting issue

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-classification, convolutional-neural-network

I have a small datset (530 images) trained on a simple CNN called AquaSight. This is the architecture.
[image: architecture of aquaSight]

I had an underfitting problem, 75% accuracy and 0.6 loss.
How can I solve the underfitting problem ? If I do Data Augmentation, will there be any improvement ?

Comment: with  21M parameters your problem might be overfitting...

Answer (score 1):

some questions will help give better answers:

1. When you say underfitting,  I assume you mean that the low accuracy is on the train set, correct? I'm asking also because with that amount of parameters for such a small training set I would be far more concerned with overfitting
2. 530 images is very small dataset, I would consider going with a pretrained architecture and possibly finetuning. CNNs trained from scratch isn't a very good solution for such data in many cases. Also, when you consider your results bad, are you comparing to something? Do you have a benchmark for what kind of accuracy you should expect on this task?
3. As a general practice, if I encounter underfitting I normally remove Dropout and put it back once I have good learning on train set and start to overfit. If you attach the loss curve we could see what's going on better
4. Data augmentation is usually more of a solution to overfitting, allowing the model to generalize better